# Do Apple Airpods Support HSP?

Tags: bluetooth, airpods

For reference I am trying to connect them as a headset on linux (where HSP is supported by PulseAudio and HFP requires more work). When I connect them, my bluetooth manager reports an entry for HFP, but I do not see an entry for HSP.

I'm not asking about how to actually connect them, but rather whether HSP is supported given that [it seems to be a subset of HFP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22936642/difference-between-hfp-and-hsp-profiles).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the Bluetooth diagnostics in System Profiler on a Mac, you'll find that the AirPods are listed as offering the "Handsfree" service, not the "Hand-set" service.

The full list of services supported are: Handsfree, Wireless iAP, AVRCP Controller, Audio Sink, AVRCP Target, AAP Server.

For the Pro model things are a bit different.

Comment: Can we get a list for the pro model? On my Linux system, only A2DP is supported, but HSP and HFP are both unavailable. So I can only listen to music on my airpods pro, but not use it as a headset.